# fos_user_security_logout route not working

Tags: php, xml, symfony, fosuserbundle

```
#app/config/security.yml
security:
    access_denied_url: /response/access-denied
    encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    acl:
    connection: default

    role_hierarchy:
        #ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        #ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email



    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                failure_handler: authentication_handler
                success_handler: authentication_handler
            logout:  
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
                target: /logout
                success_handler: authentication_handler
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https}
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https**}**
        #- { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        #- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

hi i'm new to symfony and i'm trying to logout the user but the route is not working kindly help

security.xml ---fosuserbudle config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="fos_user_security_login" pattern="/login">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:login</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_security_check" pattern="/login_check">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:check</default>
        <requirement key="_method">POST</requirement>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_security_logout" pattern="/logout">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:logout</default>
    </route>

</routes>
```

`app/config/routing.yml file`:

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

Comment: remove the target propert of logout in security.yml

Comment: @johnSmith I've tried doing that and doesn't change anything where else could the routing be except for those places

Comment: what happens when you request /logout ? 404 ? where do you get directed ? shouldnt it be @FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml ?

Comment: i'm redirected to this url http://localhost/cmtnew/web/login .the routes are defined in the @FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml

Comment: I think i just figured out my problem.i'ts with the config of apache server the directory index directive is not set hence cannot find   this url localhost/cmtnew/web/login but when i set the directory index directive to app.php or app_dev.php it works

Comment: @munenelewis Did you find a solution for this? Can you post answer?